Physical interpretation of the $\Delta l=\pm 1$ selection rule
I often get confused about what the quantum number $l$ really means since it is not an eigenvalue of a physical operator. I understand it as something that corresponds to the eigenvalue of the $\hat{L^2}$ operator, which is actually $l(l+1)$. Alternatively, I see it as the upper and the lower limit of the $m_l$ quantum number, which is the eigenvalue of the  $\hat{L}_z$ operator.
However, when discussing electric dipole selection rules, the rule $\Delta l= \pm1$ is often physically interpreted as conservation angular momentum. For instance, this resource makes the following comment on this selection rule:

This can be seen as a consequence of the fact that the angular momentum of a photon is ±$\hbar$ with the sign depending on whether we have a left or right circularly polarized
photon. Conservation of angular momentum therefore requires that the angular
momentum of the atom must change by one unit.

I get confused by this interpretation because, according to my understanding, the quantum number $l$ does not really represent angular momentum, neither does it represent a component of it. It only represents a 'state' which decides the maximum or minimum possible value of a component (z by convention) of the angular momentum. I do not understand why a change in it should map to the conservation of total angular momentum.

$l$ is but the eigenvalue of the hermitean operator
$$
\hat O\equiv \sqrt{\hat L^2+1/4} -1/2 ~,
$$
that you observed bounds $m_l$.
What it represents may be up to you to muse about, and it is rarely utilized, beyond algebraic simplifications.

I see. Does this mean that the interpretation that I talked about in a question is just a loose one?
It does make sense that the angular momentum should be conserved, I just don't see why the operator that you described should play a role in it.

Well, if $\hat L ^2$ is conserved, so is $\hat O$.

I'm not so sure why $\hat{L}^2$ should be conserved. It represents magnitude of angular momentum, which is a scalar quantity, and it may or may not be conserved. With conservation of angular momentum, would we not be interested in conservation of $\hat{L}$ as a vector? Does the operator that you describe capture the vector nature of this problem?

When $\hat L$ is conserved, all of its functions likewise are.

That makes sense. Thanks for the answer!
